# Flat UI drop down menu not working on Win7 Safari 5.1.7

Tags: drop-down-menu

Does anybody know why Flat UI drop down menu is not working on Windows7 Safari?

Official demo has this bug too: http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/ (Messages).

All other browsers seem to be working ok.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because [so] is not a replacement for customer support.

Comment: @Dukeling Support guys do not reply, don't know of other place to look for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was fixed in 1.2.5. Try using that version and see if it works.